# How to ask python docx to write in italic type just

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

How to ask python docx to write in italic type but not the entire sentence, just some words ?

I have this code :

```
names = ["names1"]
dates = ["dates1"]
client = ["client1"]

from docx import Document

document = Document('filename.docx')

paragraphs = document.paragraphs




paragraphs[0].insert_paragraph_before("       To    "+names+"         Date  "+dates)
paragraphs[0].insert_paragraph_before("                                             ")
paragraphs[0].insert_paragraph_before("      From   "+names+"             Ref   "+client)
paragraphs[0].insert_paragraph_before("                                                ")
```

I know how to specify an entire sentence to be in italic type, but not how to tell python to transform just one word in italic type.

Here, I would like to transform `To`, `Date`, `From`, `Ref` but just those four word, not the rest.

Have you an idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
p = document.add_paragraph()
p.add_run('To').italic = True
p.add_run(" "+names+" ")
p.add_run('Date').italic = True
```

and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Character formatting, such as bold and italic, is applied to a *run*. A paragraph is composed of zero or more runs.

When you specify the paragraph text as a parameter to the `.add_paragraph()` call (or `.insert_paragraph_before()` call), the resulting paragraph contains a single run containing all the specified text and having default formatting.

To do what you want, you will need to build up the paragraph text run by run, like so:

```
paragraph = paragraphs[0].insert_paragraph_before()

paragraph.add_run("       ")
run = paragraph.add_run("To")
run.italic = True
paragraph.add_run("    " + names + "         ")
run = paragraph.add_run("Date")
run.italic = True
paragraph.add_run("  " + dates)
```